# How can I move the column and row to the center

Tags: html, css

this is my second challenge in frontmentor, but honestly I haven't practice for long time.....

I am practicing to create a 3-column preview card component and I have created it by 3 columns and one row.  However, I found I could not able to moved the columns and row to the center of the page; I even tried to adjust the position of the columns by left, right by px or erm....etc.

Please advice how could I shift the columns to the center.

I have the other question, could I add any icon or button such as "learn more" into the columns?

The screenshot below is the complete of 3-column preview card component, and the url from codeply is what  I have made.  I will also put what I have created by html and css in here.

Thanks for your help and please kindly to support me to achieve it.

I think today is my time to back to the field.

[image: original of 3-column preview card component]

[my practice in codeply](https://www.codeply.com/p/CiRWfE8Yl0)

```css
/* build your own custom Bootstrap theme:
   https://themestr.app
*/

/*font*/

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
font-family: 'Big Shoulders Display', cursive;  
font-weight: bold;
color: white;
}

p {
font-family: 'Lexend Deca', sans-serif;
font-weight: 400;
color: white;
}

/* Create three equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 200px; 
}

.left{
    border-radius: 5% 0 0 5% 
}

.right {
    border-radius: 0 5% 5% 0 
 
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Big+Shoulders+Display:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lexend+Deca&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column left" style="background-color:#ff8303;">
    <article>
    <h2>Sedans</h2>
    <p>  Choose a sedan for its affordability and excellent fuel economy. Ideal for cruising in the city
  or on your next road trip.</p>
  </article> 
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#126e82;">
   <h2> SUVs</h2>
        <p>  Take an SUV for its spacious interior, power, and versatility. Perfect for your next family vacation
  and off-road adventures.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column right" style="background-color:#2f5d62;">
    <h2> Luxury</h2>
    <p>  Cruise in the best car brands without the bloated prices. Enjoy the enhanced comfort of a luxury
  rental and arrive in style.</p>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Flexbox is a good place to start.

Comment: Here's a fiddle with your answer. They closed the question before I could post: https://jsfiddle.net/pixelsmith/1j6vwcqe/

Comment: And a link to the CSS Tricks Flexbox documentation: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/